# How to minimize the script of jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I used the below tab content script. which used jquery code and jquery ui code . the jquery ui is 385kb in size so i used the min version which is 188kb.which is also a big file.. it takes some time to load on webpage.. I there any way to work the code without jquery ui ...

http://fiddle.jshell.net/joycse06/T7czp/49/show/light/#tabs-2

Comment: There are smaller libraries that support tabbing

Comment: You can build custom jQuery UI library with only `tabs` which is what that code is using from here http://jqueryui.com/download . with only tabs it becomes around 28Kb

Comment: And why are you so size obsessed? Are your users behind a 1200 baud modem?

Comment: @rene: don't forget mobile internet users.

Comment: @neworld that is true, still holds that it would be a one-time price to pay assumming mobile browser do cache as well (at least mine does)

Comment: @rene, you are right. But if you make your site load faster you make better user expierence. It's not very important, but site gets addition quality.

Comment: @rene ,there are so many images too, so it takes time to lead a page ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your custom package with custom features/components from jQuery UI download page here http://jqueryui.com/download

But if you are having problem doing this here is the demo

[DEMO](http://joynag.net/demos/tabs)

And [download](http://joynag.net/demos/tabs/tabs.zip) link of the whole package in above demo with bare minimum jQuery UI and minified JS files. It's 246Kb in total(unzipped).

Comment: Don't post non-official/3rd party download/demo links. As usual: it's broken. FIX. Till then:  -1

Answer (score 2):

You can [download](http://jqueryui.com/download) jQuery ui with only components you need. This can help to drastically reduce size of library.